# Will a bullet travel the same after going through 2 substances (in different orders)?

Tags: projectile

This may seem like a trivial question, however I am a little curious as to whether 'order matters' in the case of this system, or whether you would be able to treat any object as a 'black box' with given input and output.

My scenario is this: If you have a block of ballistics gel with a steel plate at the end, and you fire a bullet through it (Such that the bullet has enough energy to easily pierce both gel and steel) will the amount of kinetic energy (or speed) of the bullet vary depending on if it went through the gel first and than steel, or through the steel first and than the gel?

Assume that the materials are held in place such that when shot they won't move vertically or out of place.

Would the solution change if the bullet didn't get deformed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the answer is no.

Let us assume that the drag in the "black box" is viscous - then the force goes as $\rho v^2$ (plus some other terms).

If the velocity is highest while traversing the medium with the higher density, the total stopping power will be greater. It's that $v^2$ term that gets you...

Answer (score 2):

No - hitting the steel plate first will deform the bullet resulting in greater drag in the gel and lower penetration

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have however edited the question to see if this answer would remain the same if the bullet did not deform. (even though this might be considered unrealistic)